# how to download using django?

Tags: python, django

I have a download link on one of my webpage in django. 
When i download a audio file of 75mb it downloads but nothing in the audio, its 0bytes.

this is my code:

```
from django.core.servers.basehttp import FileWrapper
import mimetypes
rec_file = settings.WEB_PATH + "/media/recording/" + filename
wrapper  = FileWrapper( open(rec_file, "r"))
contentType = mimetypes.guess_type(rec_file)[0]
response = HttpResponse(wrapper, mimetype = "application/force-download")
response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(rec_file)
response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=" + filename
return response
```

i use apache server. can anyone tell me the solution ?

Comment: Strange...I have almost exactly the same code being used in production, and it works...

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't say what's wrong with your code, but you shouldn't be doing that anyways. You should serve static files directly from Apache or use [X-Sendfile](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/).

Comment: Ya , right now i am doing it using apache. I just wanted to know whether i could do it using django.